# UNEXPECTED CONSISTENCY Ubuntu cant start

Tags: boot

I'm using Ubuntu Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS from about 2 weeks and it has worked good.
I installed ubuntu on external hard drive so i can use also windows 7. But today pop-up this message:

```
/dev/sdb5: UNEXPECTED CONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.
(i.e.. without -a or -p options)
fsck exited with status code 4
The root filesystem on /dev/sdb5 requires a manual fsck

BusyBox v1.27.2 (Ubuntu 1:1.27.2-2ubuntu3.2) built-in shell (ash)
Enter "help" for a list of built-in commands
```

Answer (score 0):

So, boot from an Ubuntu LiveUSB then unmount /dev/sdb5 and do a dry run of [fsck](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/fsck.8.html)

```
sudo umount /dev/sdb5 && sudo fsck -C -M -N /dev/sdb5
```

Copy its output messages and review them, before you actually run

```
sudo fsck -C -M -r /dev/sdb5
```

which will ask you for confirmation before every change.

The Status Code 4 meant filesystem errors were left uncorrected.

Thanks to [heynnema](https://askubuntu.com/users/4272/heynnema) for the proofreading.

Comment: you mean /dev/sdb5